# mod_proxy_http can not be enabled

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have the current proxy modules enabled and working fine:

```
$ apache2ctl -M | grep proxy
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
```

When I enable `mod_proxy_http` with `a2enmod proxy_http` and `service apache2 restart`, apache returns an error as if mod_proxy was not enabled:

> oct 16 10:55:45 apachectl[15243]: apache2: Syntax error on
>   line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of
>   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy_http.load: Cannot load
>   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so into server:
>   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so: undefined symbol:
>   ap_proxy_check_connection

`ap_proxy_check_connection` is a mod_proxy.h method https://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/group__MOD__PROXY.html#ga618c0e1bede21bdd3af5d6a802671cae

Maybe some problem on module order load?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** After add LoadModule mod_proxy before `IncludeOptional` directive, the problem is same.

```
$ vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Include /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.load
Include /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.conf

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

$ apache2ctl -M | grep proxy

[Mon Oct 16 11:14:00.205439 2017] [so:warn] [pid 19944] AH01574: module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)

$ a2enmod proxy_http

Considering dependency proxy for proxy_http:
Module proxy already enabled
Enabling module proxy_http.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2

$ apache2ctl -M | grep proxy

[Mon Oct 16 11:14:11.256292 2017] [so:warn] [pid 20006] AH01574: module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
apache2: Syntax error on line 142 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy_http.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so: undefined symbol: ap_proxy_check_connection
```

Comment: a2enmod proxy && a2enmod proxy_http

Comment: Same probem: $ a2enmod proxy && a2enmod proxy_http && service apache2 restart:

apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy_http.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so: undefined symbol: ap_proxy_check_connection

Comment: how did you installed your apache?

Comment: It's a Plesk installation. Enabling http proxy module from Plesk panel the error is the same.

Comment: if you are using any hosting provider, open a ticket with this error "undefined symbol: ap_proxy_check_connection

Comment: Yes, but it's strange. A google search with "undefined symbol: ap_proxy_check_connection" returns only one result, this question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to `dist-upgrade`. Please check Plesk support [articles](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003474193-Unable-to-start-Apache-after-dist-upgrade-usr-lib-apache2-modules-mod-proxy-http-so-undefined-symbol) -

## Put this after the other LoadModule directives

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the problem as described [here](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003474193-Unable-to-start-Apache-after-dist-upgrade-usr-lib-apache2-modules-mod-proxy-http-so-undefined-symbol). To fix:

```
apt-get purge libapache2-mod-proxy-psa
a2dismod proxy
a2enmod proxy proxy_fcgi
systemctl restart apache2
```